# How to check REST requests for JWT token issued by Keycloak in JAX-RS application

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, keycloak

I'm aware that this question might not be explicitly about "programming" but I have some trouble
understanding the concept. Maybe you're able to help.

Basically, I'm deploying a WAR offering several REST endpoints based on JAX-RS to a WildFly 20 server.

Here is the baseline:

- Endpoints must be secured.
- A frontend client (based on React) shall be able to access this API.
- Keycloak is being used to authenticate users of the React app.

This is what I have so far:

#### React client

The app integrates the `keycloak-js` adapter. Any login is routed through Keycloak which issues a JWT token which is used for all further requests by the app, i.e. they contain an `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header. Check.

#### JAX-RS application in WildFly

**web.xml**

```xml
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>api</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/users/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
        <realm-name>this is ignored currently</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

**keycloak.json**

```json
{
  "realm": "my-realm",
  "auth-server-url": "${keycloak.url}/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "my-client",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "principal-attribute" : "preferred_username",
  "enable-cors": true
}
```

#### The (showcase) problem

The initial request to http://localhost:8090/api/users redirects the user the Keycloak login. After a successful login, the same URL is accessible *without sending the authentication header*. That's the point where I'm stuck. My understanding is that I need to tell my server application "Hey, check any incoming request to this URL if it contains the valid JWT token issued by Keycloak".

I assume that there are ways so that WildFly can handle exactly this. Or do I have to implement some JWT validation service my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to gets redirected to login page at all and the `/users` path is not used to serve any web contents (e.g. jsp, html, etc.), then it's safe to tell the Keycloak that `/users` is only accessible via "Bearer" tokens. Then in cases that such a token doesn't exist in the request, it just returns proper HTTP status code and doesn't do anything. You can do this by setting `bearer-only` property to `true` in the *keycloak.json* file. So your file should look like this:

```json
{
  "realm": "my-realm",
  "auth-server-url": "${keycloak.url}/auth",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "my-client",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "principal-attribute" : "preferred_username",
  "enable-cors": true,
  "bearer-only": true
}
```